# Outlook mailapp ribbon button

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm developing an outlook mailapp addin. I added ribbon button to open a task pane where the addin is loaded. However I encountered a strange error. It can not open a task pane because of some COM addins. See the attached picture for details:
[image]

If I click manage button I get the popup with error.
There is a O365 account configured.
I'm using Outlook 2016 version 1705 (Build 8201.2102 Click to run)

I tried to stop my COM addins step by step and try to open the mailapp addin but I have received the same issue.

Any suggestion?

Update:

Screenshot about COM addins:

[image: COM addins]

**I have also a custom forms installed!**